# How can I find the $n$ th derivatve of this function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, induction, pattern-recognition

> Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}\,\,\,\,\,\ \forall x\in[0,1].$

It is not difficult to find first few derivatives of this function as

$$f'(x)=-\dfrac1{2^2}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}$$

$$f''(x)=-\frac1{2^4}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-3/2}(1-x)^{-1}-\frac1{2^3}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-3/2}$$

$$f'''(x)=-\frac3{2^6}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-5/2}(1-x)^{-3/2}-\frac3{2^5}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-3/2}(1-x)^{-2}-\frac3{2^4}(1+\sqrt{1-x})^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-5/2}$$

However it is difficult to observe a pattern between these derivatives.
How can I find the $n$th derivative of $f$?

Comment: Faà di Bruno might be useful

Comment: Did you mean [this one?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2wpCbv5fRAhUHOyYKHcOqATkQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFa%25C3%25A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula&usg=AFQjCNFkFbWtXGTut356TvPEcw_mEfJHYQ) I just thought to use a subtitution like $x=\sin^2\theta.$ But not sure.

Comment: @Nil: that is a clever idea. You may also notice that $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

Comment: Are you trying to get the nth derivative as a function of x or do you want it to be evaluated at some point?

Comment: You may also differentiate multiple times both sides of $$ f(x)\,f'(x) = -\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x}}.$$

Comment: @DavidQuinn: I need a formula for $n$th derivative.

Comment: Does it need to be explicitly in terms of x?

Comment: If you are just interested in $f^{(n)}(0)$, through the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1\pm x}$ it is straightforward to deduce the Taylor series of $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}\right).$$

Comment: @DavidQuinn: Yes. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: You give me a nice idea. I will try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit*.  One may use the following result.

**Hint**. Let $f$ be $n$-times differentiable over some interval $(0,b).$ Then

> $$
> \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\left[f(\sqrt{x})\frac{}{}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}\frac{1}{(2\sqrt{x})^{n+k}}f^{(n-k)}(\sqrt{x}).\tag1
> $$

Since 
$$
\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}\right)
$$then one may apply $(1)$ to 
$$
f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right),\qquad 0<x<1,\tag2
$$ observing that
$$
f^{(k)}(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2k)!}{(2k-1)2^{2k}k!}\frac1{(1+x)^{k-\frac12}}-\frac{(2k)!}{(2k-1)2^{2k}k!}\frac1{(1-x)^{k-\frac12}}\right). \tag3
$$

---

Comment: I differentiate few times and observe that your $(1)$ is absolutely correct.  How did you obtain it?

Comment: @Nil I had this in my notes, but I've found a useful source (pp. 157-158): https://archive.org/details/Comtet_Louis_-_Advanced_Coatorics

Comment: Thanks for your helpful link. It explains everything even more than I expect :)

Comment: @Nil You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just a partial answer. Since
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}\right)\tag{1}$$
and
$$ \sqrt{1-x} = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1)4^n}x^n \tag{2}$$
we have that:
$$ \sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x} = -2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{4n}{2n}}{(4n-1)16^n} x^{2n} $$
and:
$$ f(x) = -\sqrt{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{4n}{2n}}{(4n-1)16^n}\,x^{n} \tag{3} $$
so that:
$$ f^{(n)}(0) = -\sqrt{2}\,\frac{\binom{4n-2}{2n-1}(n-1)!}{16^n}\tag{4} $$
for any $n\geq 1$. About the general expression of $f^{(n)}(x)$, there is no shame in exploiting our pattern matching abilities. It looks like:
$$ f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c(n,k) \left(1+\sqrt{1-x}\right)^{-(2k-1)/2}(1-x)^{n-k/2} \tag{5}$$
and it is enough to differentiate both sides of $(5)$ wrt to $x$ to derive a recurrence relation for the coefficients $c(n,k)$.

Comment: Nice derivation. (+1)